# How to clear ListView on Fragment when back button pressed?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-adapter, onbackpressed

All data from that `ListView` is provided by a **`CursorAdapter`**.
Whenever I pressed back button and `return` to activity, then click on the activity to start my `fragment`, all previous data still there stacking on top of each other.

Comment: Simply make ArrayList.clear() and notifydataSetChanged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `public` a method in fragment which will clear your list and call that method from its parent activity's On `onBackPressed` using fragment's instance.

Answer (score 1):

1) Create an interface `BackPressedListener`:

```
public interface BackPressedListener {
    void onBackPressed();
}
```

2) In your activity, you can override `onBackPressed()`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    List<Fragment> fragmentList = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
    if (fragmentList != null) {
        for(Fragment fragment : fragmentList){
           if(fragment instanceof BackPressedListener){
               ((BackPressedListener)fragment).onBackPressed();
           }
        }
    }
}
```

3) Implement the `interface` `BackPressedListener`, on your `fragment`.  You would override the `onBackPressed` method in your `fragment`, clear your `list` containing the elements and then notify the `adapter` of the changes as below:

```
   @Override
        public void onBackPressed()
        {
             arrayList.clear();
             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
             finish();
        }
```

Comment: Should I put this code on my activity class? What arrayList refer to? I create the ListView in Fragment.

Comment: That "Fragment" in List<Fragment>, should I change it to my Fragment name? Or is it an android class that I need to import?

Comment: No. That is the type of Object the list holds, in this case a Fragment.

Comment: I get "getFraments can only be called from the same library group" error

Comment: Add //noinspection RestrictedApi above the line which gives you the error.

Comment: That error now disappear but I don't know what arrayList belong to. The only thing that hold the data are a ListView and Adapter. and both can use .clear()

Comment: That's your list, the one you pass as argument to the adapter when you create an instance of it.

Comment: It's a Cursor. All my data are held in a database

Answer (score 0):

When returned to the activity after pressing back button call:

```
arraylist.clear();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: So should I add this to my Fragment or the Activity class? Sorry for newbie question

Comment: From my knowledge, we can't do onBackPressed on Fragment

Comment: is it the activity that contains the listview?

Comment: No, its my fragment. My fragment's initiated by the activity

Comment: So from main activity your are loading a fragment? when loading the fragment are you calling fragmentTransaction.replace() or fragmentTransaction.add() ?

Comment: This is what I did in my activity class:

FixtureInfoFragment mFixtureInfo = new FixtureInfoFragment();
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
     .replace(R.id.containerMain, mFixtureInfo)
     .commit();

Comment: do this in your fragment:

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    //mContainer.removeAllViews();
    ViewGroup mContainer = (ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.container);
    mContainer.removeAllViews();
    super.onDestroyView();
}

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
      try {
           arraylist.clear();
           listView.removeAllViews();
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
```